# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Signalr pass data from authorization requirement to hub

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an authorization requirement which makes sure the access token in the http header is valid:

```
class AccessTokenRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<AccessTokenRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement 
{
     protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessTokenRequirement requirement)
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

I am adding this requirement to the mvc pipeline in the startup.cs class as follows:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AccessToken", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(
       services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<AccessTokenRequirement>()));
});
```

I then use this requirement on my signalr hubs like so:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AccessToken")]
public class MyHub : Hub
```

Inside the authorization requirement I check the token and identify the user by hitting the database. My question is how can I access the user details INSIDE the hub methods? What is an elegant way to pass information from inside an authorization requirement to my hub methods? 
I have read into the Identity concept in asp.net but found it to be difficult to comprehend.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the `ClaimsPrincipal` inside your Hub via `Context.User`.

Is that the information you want or is there something else you want access to in your Hub?

Comment: I didn't realise I could access that from inside my hub, thanks a lot!